# Is it possible to add box shadowing to inputs in forms css?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to add some snazzy effects to my input boxes and one I found was box shadowing, I looked at the **w3schools** tutorial for box shadowing and tried multiple things to add it to my input box:

```
.l_input {
  box-shadow: 10px;
}
```

That didn't seem to work for my code. I also tried to use it using a hover pseudo effect and it again didn't work for that, the pseudo code I tried doing:

```
.l_input {
  box-shadow: 5px;
}
.l_input:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

And again that didn't seem to work, if this is the right syntax for how the code should work or I am doing a small mistake thanks in advance, I have thought that maybe it isn't supported for inputs, but that sounded weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give box shadow like following way:

```
.l_input {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
}
```

You should give at least first two value.

First two describe horizontal shadow and vertical shadow. Third one is blur and color.

```
box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius] [optional spread radius] [color];
```

**[Reference link:](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/)**

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osndtyqx/)**

And you can give effect to shadow following way.

```
.l_input {
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
}
.l_input:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osndtyqx/2/)**

Answer (score 6):

```css
.l_input  {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* hover effect  */
.l_input:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="l_input"> Content <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be worked with below code.If your class is `.l_input` then it will be worked.Its depends on your mark.

```
.l_input {
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
}
```

If not then try below code:

You can see in **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xp1ke87g/)** .

```css
body {
  background: #ccc
}
.box h3 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}
.box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 1
 * ===============================================*/

.effect1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/

.effect2 {
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before,
.effect2:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 3
 * ===============================================*/

.effect3 {
  position: relative;
}
.effect3:before {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 4
 * ===============================================*/

.effect4 {
  position: relative;
}
.effect4:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 5
 * ===============================================*/

.effect5 {
  position: relative;
}
.effect5:before,
.effect5:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
.effect5:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 6
 * ===============================================*/

.effect6 {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect6:before,
.effect6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
  border-radius: 100px / 10px;
}
.effect6:after {
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 7
 * ===============================================*/

.effect7 {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect7:before,
.effect7:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
  border-radius: 100px / 10px;
}
.effect7:after {
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
/*==================================================
 * Effect 8
 * ===============================================*/

.effect8 {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect8:before,
.effect8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
  border-radius: 100px / 10px;
}
.effect8:after {
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
  transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect1">
  <h3>Effect 1</h3>
</div>

<div class="box effect2">
  <h3>Effect 2</h3>
</div>

<div class="box effect3">
  <h3>Effect 3</h3>
</div>

<div class="box effect4">
  <h3>Effect 4</h3>
</div>

<div class="box effect5">
  <h3>Effect 5</h3>
</div>

<div class="box effect6">
  <h3>Effect 6</h3>
</div>

<div class="box effect7">
  <h3>Effect 7</h3>
</div>

<div class="box effect8">
  <h3>Effect 8</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```css
.l_input  {
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #666;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  border:1px solid #999;
}

.l_input:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 15px #666;
 transition: 0.2s all linear;
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" class="l_input">
```